# Scene save&load works fine when playing scene directly,but when i load from main menu it's null exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

when i starting my game on the game scene,everything is fine,but when i load from menu,first time is ok,then there is saving data to json,and when i come back to main menu,and then again press play it's " Object reference not set to an instance of an object " for my saveScript which is attached to empty gameObject on game scene.

loading just

`SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("game");`

**SAVE SCRIPT**

```
public void PopulateSaveData(SaveData sd)
    {
        //character
        sd.s_XP = XP;
        respawnScript.instance.PopulateSaveData(sd);
        sd.s_x = gameObject.transform.position.x;
        sd.s_y = gameObject.transform.position.y;
        sd.s_z = gameObject.transform.position.z;

        playerHealth.instance.PopulateSaveData(sd);
        //sword
        playerSword.instance.PopulateSaveData(sd);
        //inventory
        Inventory.instance.PopulateSaveData(sd);
        //sd.s_allItemsPositions = allItemsPositions;
        //sd.s_allPotionInteractions = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<potionInteraction>().ToList();
        if (allPotionInteractionO.Count > 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("ALL POTIONS COUNT " + allPotionInteractionO[0]);
            sd.s_allPotionInteractions = allPotionInteractionO;
        }
        
        sd.s_allWeaponInteractions = all_swords;
        sd.s_allWeaponInteractionsGO = all_swordsGO;

        for (int i = 0; i < all_swordsGO.Count; i++)
        {
            sd.s_allSwordsRotation.Add(all_swordsGO[i].transform.rotation);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < all_swordsGO.Count; i++)
        {
            //because some objects can be destroyed thats why im initializing list again
            //allInteractableGameObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("interactable object").ToList();
            // sd.s_allItemsPositions.Add(allInteractableGameObjects[i].transform.position);
            sd.s_allSwordsPositions.Add(all_swordsGO[i].transform.position);

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < allPotionInteractionO.Count; i++)
        {
            sd.s_allPotionsPositions.Add(allPotionInteractionO[i].transform.position);
        }
        ///going through list and check if there is used item,then saving its bool to another list at same position
        for (int i = 0; i < allPotionInteractionO.Count; i++)
        {
            if (allPotionInteractionO[i].isUsed)
            {
                allPotionsIsUsed[i] = true;
            }
        }
        sd.s_allPotionsIsUsed = allPotionsIsUsed;
        //quest part
        for (int i = 0; i < allNPCS.Count; i++)
        {
            if (allNPCS[i].quest == null)
            {
                allNpcQuests[i] = null;
            }
        }
        sd.s_allQuests = allNpcQuests;
        if(MarieleQuest.instance.currentMarieleQuest!=null)
        {
            sd.s_currentQuest = MarieleQuest.instance.currentMarieleQuest;
        }
        foreach (Slot slot in slotsToSave)
        {
            slot.PopulateSaveData(sd);

        }
        //enemies
        foreach (EnemyStats enemy in all_enemies)
        {
            enemy.PopulateSaveData(sd);
        }
        //procedural enemies
        foreach (ProceduralStats enemy in all_procedural_enemies)
        {
            enemy.PopulateSaveData(sd);
        }
    }
```

**LOAD**

```
public void LoadFromSaveData(SaveData sd)
    {
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "game")
        {
            //character
            XP = sd.s_XP;
            if (sd.s_HP > 0)
            {
                playerHealth.instance.LoadFromSaveData(sd);
            }
            else if (sd.s_HP == 0)
            {
                playerHealth.instance.currentHealth = 100;
            }
            if (sd.s_respawnObject != null)
            {
                respawnScript.instance.LoadFromSaveData(sd);
            }
            if (sd.s_x != 0 && sd.s_y != 0 && sd.s_z != 0)
            {
                gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(sd.s_x, sd.s_y, sd.s_z);
            }
            //sword
            if (sd.s_sword != null && sd.s_temp != null && sd.s_currentSword != null && sd.s_currentSwordGO != null)
            {
                playerSword.instance.LoadFromSaveData(sd);

            }
            else
            {
                playerSword.instance.currentSwordGameObject = GameObject.Find("character/mixamorig:Hips/mixamorig:Spine/mixamorig:Spine1/" + playerSword.instance.currentSwordGameObject.name);
                playerSword.instance.temp = playerSword.instance.currentSwordGameObject;
            }


            //potions
            if (sd.s_allPotionsIsUsed.Count > 0)
            {
                allPotionsIsUsed = sd.s_allPotionsIsUsed;
            }
            //quest
            if (sd.s_allQuests.Count > 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("SD ALL QUESTS" + sd.s_allQuests);
                allNpcQuests = sd.s_allQuests;
            }
            if (sd.s_allQuests.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < allNPCS.Count; i++)
                {
                    allNPCS[i].quest = allNpcQuests[i];
                }
            }
            if (sd.s_currentQuest != null)
            {
                MarieleQuest.instance.currentMarieleQuest = sd.s_currentQuest;
            }
          

            if (sd.s_allPotionInteractions.Count > 0)//second pattern in if is changed(FOR REMEMBER)
            {
                Debug.Log("SD ALL POTIONS > 0");
                if (sd.s_allPotionInteractions[0] != null)
                {
                    allPotionInteractionO = sd.s_allPotionInteractions;
                }
                else
                {
                    allPotionInteractionO = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<potionInteraction>().ToList();
                }
                for (int b = 0; b < allPotionInteractionO.Count; b++)
                {
                    allPotionInteractionO[b].isUsed = allPotionsIsUsed[b];
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < allPotionInteractionO.Count; i++)
                {

                    if (allPotionInteractionO[i].isUsed)
                    {
                        allPotionInteractionO[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    }
                }
            }


            Inventory.instance.LoadFromSaveData(sd);
            if (sd.s_allWeaponInteractions.Count > 0)
            {

                //all_swords = sd.s_allWeaponInteractions;
               // all_swordsGO = sd.s_allWeaponInteractionsGO;
                for (int i = 0; i < all_swordsGO.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!Inventory.instance.itemsGameObjects.Contains(all_swordsGO[i])
                    && all_swordsGO[i] != playerSword.instance.currentSwordGameObject)
                    {
                        all_swordsGO[i].SetActive(true);

                        all_swordsGO[i].transform.rotation = sd.s_allSwordsRotation[i];


                    }
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < sd.s_allSwordsPositions.Count; j++)
                {
                    //Debug.Log(sd.s_allItemsPositions[j] + " " + allInteractableGameObjects[j].name);
                    all_swordsGO[j].transform.position = sd.s_allSwordsPositions[j];
                    allPotionInteractionO[j].transform.position = sd.s_allPotionsPositions[j];
                }
            }

            foreach (Slot slot in slotsToSave)
            {
                slot.LoadFromSaveData(sd);

            }
            //enemies
            foreach (EnemyStats enemy in all_enemies)
            {
                enemy.LoadFromSaveData(sd);
            }
            foreach (string id in dead_enemies_ids)
            {
                SaveData.EnemyData enemyData = new SaveData.EnemyData();
                enemyData.e_Health = 0;
                enemyData.e_id = id;
                sd.enemyData.Add(enemyData);
            }
            //procedural enemies
            foreach (ProceduralStats enemy in all_procedural_enemies)
            {
                enemy.LoadFromSaveData(sd);
            }
            foreach (string id in all_procedural_ids)
            {
                SaveData.ProceduralEnemyData enemyData = new SaveData.ProceduralEnemyData();
                enemyData.e_ProcHealth = 0;
                enemyData.e_ProcId = id;
                sd.proceduralEnemyData.Add(enemyData);
            }
        }
    }
```

these two scripts just writing data to lists,and reading it from saved file,
saving is called once **OnApplicationQuit()**
load called at the end of **Start()**
when i open scene **game** just from itself and close and load again,everything work fine,because its destroying objects and load them again,but
once i start from main menu,from there do **LoadScene("game")** i'm getting error that some fields are not exist **anymore**,but it's like unreal
**SaveData script which have all info and store it to file,then read**

```
public class SaveData : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        
        
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        s_inventoryGO = new List<GameObject>();
        Debug.Log("s_inventoryGO" + s_inventoryGO.Count);
    }
    //character saving
    public int s_XP;
    public GameObject s_respawnObject;
    public float s_x;
    public float s_y;
    public float s_z;
    //inventory
    public List<Item> s_inventory = new List<Item>();
    public List<GameObject> s_inventoryGO = new List<GameObject>();
    public List<GameObject> s_allGameObjectInventory = new List<GameObject>();
    
    public List<GameObject> s_allInteractableObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    public List<potionInteraction> s_allPotionInteractions = new List<potionInteraction>();
    public List<weaponInteract> s_allWeaponInteractions = new List<weaponInteract>();
    public List<GameObject> s_allWeaponInteractionsGO = new List<GameObject>();
    public List<Quaternion> s_allSwordsRotation = new List<Quaternion>();
    public List<Vector3> s_allSwordsPositions = new List<Vector3>();
    public List<Vector3> s_allPotionsPositions = new List<Vector3>();
    public List<bool> s_allPotionsIsUsed = new List<bool>();
    public List<Quest> s_allQuests = new List<Quest>();

    public Quest s_currentQuest;
    public int s_HP;
    [System.Serializable]
    public struct SlotsData
    {
        public Item s_slotItem;
        public string s_id;
        //public Sprite s_icon ;
    }
    public List<SlotsData> s_slots = new List<SlotsData>();
    
    //sword
    public Transform s_sword;
    public GameObject s_currentSwordGO;
    public GameObject s_temp;
    public swordEquipping s_currentSword;
    //enemy saving
    [System.Serializable]
    public struct EnemyData
    {
        public int e_Health;
        public string e_id;
    }
    public List<EnemyData> enemyData = new List<EnemyData>();
    //procedural enemy saving
    [System.Serializable]
    public struct ProceduralEnemyData
    {
        public int e_ProcHealth;
        public string e_ProcId;
    }
    public List<ProceduralEnemyData> proceduralEnemyData = new List<ProceduralEnemyData>();
    public string toJson()
    {
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(this);
    }
    public void LoadFromJson(string json)
    {

        JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(json, this);
    }


}
```

Comment: I can post an answer once I know more about your issues, but I believe it is because however you are saving has a `DontDestroyOnLoad` and you have public inspector references. When you go back to the scene, this object still exists, but it loses all of its references as it is a new scene and the references it had are long gone. You can get all of these references when the scene loads again.

Comment: now i've tested a little bit,lists of types like <Item> are loading fine,but all not empty lists of GameObjects are lost after going to menu,i don't know to save them or maybe not destroy.
when i load start is called,and all definitions are set,but only when i have GameObjects lists,then there is a problem

Comment: The reason the Items work is most likely because they are a prefab. Meaning their reference exists outside of the scene. The GameObjects only exist in the scene. When you load into the game, then come back, they will no longer exist.

Comment: ok,i understand,but then how to save gameobjects,DontDestroyOnLoad doesnt work how  i expect,but even if it will problem is when i stop playing game at all,then i turn it on -> go to game from menu and getting error,maybe it's starting earlier than gameobjects are loaded in scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `DontDestroyOnLoad` wherever you want this object to exist, make a copy of it in your scene if you want the data stored to persist between your game session.

Here is a snippet from the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)

```
void Awake()
{
    GameObject[] objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("music");

    if (objs.Length > 1)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}
```

It will search for other objects in the scene with the same tag. If it finds it, it will destroy itself. What you can do here is have a public Init() function on your script. When a new scene is loaded with the object and your object already finds an instance of itself, it can pass the local references to the existing object. Something like...

```
public GameObject objRef1;
public GameObject objRef2;
  
public void Init(GameObject obj1, GameObject obj2)
{
    objRef1 = obj1;
    objRef2 = obj2;
    ...
    etc.
}
```

Inside of the `Awake()` of the new object, you would call the existing objects Init with the local references it has, which work as it loaded with your scene.

```
void Awake()
{
    // make the tag unique so you only grab objects of this save type
    GameObject[] objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("yourObjectsTag");

    if (objs.Length > 1)
    {
        objs[0].GetComponent<YourScriptName>().Init(obj1, obj2, ..., etc.);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}
```

In this approach it means you have a local copy of your DontDestroyOnLoad object in every scene so when the existing one loads in, it can just grab the references from it.

Comment: wow,my question is,i need to save gamobject which have childrens all gameobjects i need or i need to save object which have the script which loads everything,so the lists will not be destoyed?

Comment: Are you trying to save the state of a scene so you can load it back up as it was before? Or are you just having issues loading back into a scene with an object that has DontDestroyOnLoad. You can have a list or have them be individual objects. It is up to you. And it depends I suppose if you are handling these objects as scripts or game objects. If they are scripts, then you can just pass the scripts. I just use the `public GameObject objRef1 and objRef2` as examples. You can use anything in place of them.

Comment: honestly i can't explain you my problem,ok i will write as steps
1)starting main menu->going to game(now script which load saved data is running ok)
2)stop playing game at all(just stop),it's saving everything fine because its working when i test it without menu
3)start again,pressing button in menu and go to game and now it's say that there is null object reference
I dont understand it because it's new game,so everything set up in start before,why is there null,maybe objects are loading after start,but how, even if i will DontDestroy it this doesnt make sense,because i turn off game.

Comment: @tommer I would need more code to tell you about the null reference. If it works fine before, then it has to be something with how you are saving / loading data. It is hard for me to know what the issue is without seeing the whole problem. Null references are usually due to missing references in the inspector or corrupted data.

Comment: how can i show use code?
write it as comment here or ?

Comment: @tommer I would edit your question and paste it there. Use [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) as a guide to format it properly.

Comment: @tommer Just to narrow it down, can you post the specific null errors you are getting or which objects are null after the load? It would help to figure out the specific issue.

Comment: I am also pretty sure you can not serialize gameobjects using JSON. That might be why you are getting null references

Comment: I personally would not store any complex data types. Is there a reason you need to save an entire gameobject? Store the primitive data types you need from it, then load those parts in. Same with saving lists of objects. If the structs / classes are not marked a Serializable they will not be serialized using JSON.

Comment: so i removed serializing,but still same, i need to save gameobject,why then it works when i load game scene without menu,maybe there is some problem with loading,i've tried do with some delay, but nothing, i'm getting error now "The variable s_inventoryGO of SaveData doesn't exist anymore."

Comment: @tommer When I need to serialize game objects such as items I store an item reference manager. Then store an index in the list when serializing so instead of serializing the object itself, I serialize information to reference it when it loads.